# Garbled text in long emails

Tags: emails

I'm working on a Drupal 6 site using the mimemail module and have run into a problem. When I send emails longer then 900 ish characters the email comes through as a garbled text. Running this through base64 decode returns the correct html markup.

Any ideas on why the length of an email would cause it to do this? From hunting around the only thing that sounds possible is that I know the email standard only allows about 900 characters per line. But then I would imagine mimemail would handle this natively?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are my HTML emails so garbled?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/99910/why-are-my-html-emails-so-garbled)

Comment: I'm hesitant to close this as a dup as the linked question doesn't seems to really have a solution.  I am also uncertain whether the Drupal version number matters here.

Comment: I read the question suggested as a duplicate and my situation differs. The emails being sent here use the default mimemail template and do not have any inline styles or broken tags.